# SharePoint 2010 OOTB filtering and sorting is not working in XsltListViewWebPart in Arabic

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part, sorting, multilingual

I am working on a multilingual site in English and Arabic. I have some pages with XsltListViewWebPart to view custom lists with no more than 12 fields to display. These are connecting webparts and provide filter values to another XsltListViewWebPart on same page.

When I open this page in Arabic its OOTB filtering and sorting does not work and also it does not show Display form when i click on Title of any of the list items.

When I click on any of the column headers it shows the filtering and sorting menu with all option and filtering values but after click nothing happens.

However if there is any lookup field in same webpart and when i click on that it shows display form of that particulat lookup item.

This happenss only if I open these pages in Arabic.. in English everything works fine.

Nothing is customized but conditional formating on one column and added connection between webparts.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/6b87864d-0d47-4b32-a5be-d541c24d17f3 Does this nor work for you?

Comment: That didn't seem to me a proper answer, because it works in English... and its not only about Sort, its about OOB filtering as well.. Do you suggest that if I use his recommendation I will solve the problem? It was mark as answered by the forum automatically :/

Comment: No it only stays on here for a short amount of time, the bounty just expired that was all. The above fix should fix your issue, well patch it. This won't be fixed now for 2010, maybe you could move to 2013 and see if it's fixed there?

Comment: Hugh Wood, can't move to SharePoint 2013 making this issue as a reason :)... And don't you think SP 2013 will have its own limitations and issue :P

Comment: Yes perhaps but at least this seems to work :D